# Trouble storing data for a small game

Tags: php

Ok so im having trouble with a project im working on. Its going minesweeper in php but in the bases of the game I can't get the different cell blocks to store their information. Ive tried using session and get, but i can't seem to figure out how to store the information or where to put the code. Below is the basic game code: any ideas?

updated: I really appreciate the help I've been trying to tackle this for awhile now. I am unsure of where to place some of the session values. This does not look right to me:

```
<html>
<body>


<?php
// ~~~~~~~~~  VARIABLES  ~~~~~~~~~~
session_start();
$_SESSION[$piece] = $piece;

$default_board = "default_board";
$filename = "currentproject.php";


$width = "20px";
$height = "20px";
$y_coord = 50;
$how_many_spots = 25;

echo "<table border=1>";
$_SESSION['clicks'] = array();
for ($y=24;$y!=0;--$y) {
    $y_coord += $height;
    $x_coord = 50;

    for ($x=24;$x!=0;--$x){

        $x_coord += $width; $cell_sum = $x + $y; $remainder = $cell_sum%2; // some math
        if (isset($piece[$x][$y])) {
            $background_color = "#991122"; //shows a mine
        } else if ($remainder == 0) {
            $background_color = "#CCCCCC";
        } else $background_color = "#AAAAAA";

        echo "<div onclick=\"javascript:document.location.href='$filename?xcord=$x&ycord=$y';\" style=\"border: 1px solid black; background-color: $background_color; position: absolute;left: $x_coord; top: $y_coord; width: $width; height: $height;\">";
        echo "</div>";
        $_SESSION['clicks'][$xcord][$ycord] = False;
        $_SESSION['clicks'][$_GET['xcord']][$_GET['ycord']] = True;
        // ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ MINES GO HERE ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
        while ($how_many_spots!=0){
            $i = rand(1,24);
            $e = rand(1,24);
            if (!isset($piece[$i][$e])){
                $piece[$i][$e] = "mine";
                --$how_many_spots;

            }
        }
    }
    print ("<br>");
}
$_GET['xcord'] = $xcord;
$_GET['ycord'] = $ycord;

?>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "store"? I don't see any sort of database interaction in your code.

Comment: You might find an MVVM model better for this.  USer clicks javascripts submits AJAX to a _different_ backend handler than servers the page ( thus a lot of simplicity there), gets back response, renders it.

Comment: See updated code for a working example - I am posting this comment here since I was not sure if my comment below would send a flag to you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It could be done using the `$_SESSION` and `$_GET` variables. Following is a working example. It was fun to work out and I hope it helps. Note that the code for alternating grey boxes is not quite right and I did not fix it. I also added options for grid size and number of mines as playing with a 25 x 25 grid gave 625 boxes with 25 mines - a rather difficult chance of survival. I defaulted the grid to 4x4 with 1 mine (I like winning) and you can of course change that.

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function gameover($won){
        if ($won){
            alert("Game Over - You won");
        }
        else {
            alert("Game Over - You lost");
        }
    }
</script>
</head>

<?php
    session_start();
    $filename = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
    $gridsize = 4;
    $nummines = 1;

    if (isset($_SESSION['piece'])){
        // board has been set up previously - game in progress
        if (isset($_GET['new_game'])){
            // start a new game
            unset($_SESSION['piece']);
        }
    }
    if (isset($_SESSION['grid_size'])){
        // game in progress
        $gridsize = $_SESSION['grid_size'];
        $nummines = $_SESSION['num_mines'];
    }
    if (isset($_GET['grid_size'])){
        // New Game - set from form choice
        $gridsize = $_GET['grid_size'];
        $nummines = $_GET['num_mines'];
        $_SESSION['grid_size'] = $gridsize;
        $_SESSION['num_mines'] = $nummines;
    }
?>

<body>
    <div>
    <form name="minesweeper" action="<?php echo $filename ?>" method="GET">
        Enter Grid Size: <input type="input" value="<?php echo $gridsize ?>" name="grid size">
        Enter Number of Mines: <input type="input" value="<?php echo $nummines ?>" name="num_mines">
        <input type="submit" value="New Game" name="new_game"> 
    </form>
    </div>


<?php
// ~~~~~~~~~    VARIABLES   ~~~~~~~~~~
$default_board = "default_board";

$width = "20px";
$height = "20px";
$y_coord = 50;
$how_many_spots = $gridsize;

echo "<table border=1>";

if (isset($_SESSION['piece'])){
    // board has been set up previously - game in progress
    if (isset($_GET['x'])){
        // if cell clicked
        if ($_SESSION['piece'][$_GET['x']][$_GET['y']] == "mine"){
            // if mine - game over 
            $game_over = true;
            $_SESSION['piece'][$_GET['x']][$_GET['y']] = "explode";
        }
        else {
            // mark clicked
            $_SESSION['piece'][$_GET['x']][$_GET['y']] = "clicked";
        }
    }

    // draw board
    $clickcounter = 0;
    for ($y=$gridsize;$y!=0;--$y) {
        $y_coord += $height;
        $x_coord = 50;

        for ($x=$gridsize;$x!=0;--$x){              
                $x_coord += $width; $cell_sum = $x + $y; $remainder = $cell_sum%2; // some math

                if ($_SESSION['piece'][$x][$y] === "explode") {
                     $background_color = "Black"; 
                     $game_over = true;
                }
                elseif ($_SESSION['piece'][$x][$y] === "clicked") {
                    // clicked
                     $background_color = "Green"; 
                     $clickcounter++;
                } 
                elseif ($_SESSION['piece'][$x][$y] === "mine" && isset($game_over)) {
                    //shows all mines when game over
                    $background_color = "#991122"; 
                } 
                elseif ($remainder == 0) {
                    $background_color = "#CCCCCC";
                } 
                else {
                    $background_color = "#AAAAAA";
                }

                echo "<div onclick=\"javascript:document.location.href='$filename?x=$x&y=$y';\" style=\"border: 1px solid black; background-color: $background_color; position: absolute;left: $x_coord; top: $y_coord; width: $width; height: $height;\">";
                echo "</div>";

        }
    }
    if (isset($game_over)){
        echo "<script language='JavaScript'>gameover(false)</script>";                   
    }
    elseif ($clickcounter >= ($gridsize * $gridsize) - $nummines){
        echo "<script language='JavaScript'>gameover(true)</script>";                    
    }
}
else{

    for ($y=$gridsize;$y!=0;--$y) {
        $y_coord += $height;
        $x_coord = 50;

        for ($x=$gridsize;$x!=0;--$x){
                $x_coord += $width; $cell_sum = $x + $y; $remainder = $cell_sum%2; // some math
                // shows a mine for debugging
                if (isset($_SESSION['piece'][$x][$y]) && $_SESSION['piece'][$x][$y]=="mine") {
                    if ($remainder == 0){
                        $background_color = "#CCCCCC";
                    }
                    else {
                        $background_color = "#AAAAAA";
                    }
                } 
                elseif ($remainder == 0) {
                    $_SESSION['piece'][$x][$y] = false;
                    $background_color = "#CCCCCC";
                } 
                else {
                    $_SESSION['piece'][$x][$y] = false;
                    $background_color = "#AAAAAA";
                }

                echo "<div onclick=\"javascript:document.location.href='$filename?x=$x&y=$y';\" style=\"border: 1px solid black; background-color: $background_color; position: absolute;left: $x_coord; top: $y_coord; width: $width; height: $height;\">";
                echo "</div>";
                // ~~~~~~~~~MINES GO HERE ~~~~~
                while ($nummines!=0){
                        $i = rand(1,$gridsize);
                        $e = rand(1,$gridsize);
                        $_SESSION['piece'][$i][$e] = "mine";
                        --$nummines;
                }
        }
        print ("<br>");
    }
}
?>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for the input I updated the code up front but some of my session values dont look quite right to me.

Comment: Thank you so much this is going to save me a ton of time! Really appreciate it.

Comment: You're welcome. If you found the post helpful, please mark it as the correct answer by clicking the check next to the post. This both completes the post saying it was answered and credits the user. If the post was helpful but not the "answer," you can click the up triangle above the number.